# android best layout to display image button that will fills the screen

Tags: android, layout

what's the best layout to use to display a series of image button, side by side (as displayed in attached image), and that will fills the screen horizontally when the orientation changes to horizontal (as attached)?

[horizontal orientation http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/657/layoutxs.png](http://img254.imageshack.us/img254/657/layoutxs.png)
[vertical orientation http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/2428/layouthy.png](http://img208.imageshack.us/img208/2428/layouthy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<GridView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:numColumns="auto_fit" >
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use something like FlowLayout, which doesn't exist in Android. You can make your own, however. More information

- [How can I do something like a FlowLayout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)
- http://nishantvnair.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/flowlayout-in-android/

I have an activity with a layout similar to yours, but I use a different method. What I do is define a different xml layout for landscape and portrait. So I have `layout-port/mylayout.xml` and `layout-land/mylayout.xml` and the system determines which one the activity should use.

Answer (score 0):

just create two separate layout files and call setContentView() in your onOrientationChanged().