# Can the Android Flow virtual layout handle variable-width Views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Android recently introduced [Flow virtual layout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow) but all of the examples I've seen show child Views that have the same width so it ends up laying out in a grid, instead of a jagged flow.

I've seen variable width handles for [flexbox-layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#supported-attributes) and [Dhaval Solanki's FlowLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41013282/2848676).

One other person asked a similar question ([Which android layout to use for distributing variable width buttons to fill a screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549047/which-android-layout-to-use-for-distributing-variable-width-buttons-to-fill-a-sc)), but they were asking generally how to do it, whereas I'm asking specifically how to do it with Flow.

Can Flow handle variable-width Views?  How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how it can be achieved (`ConstraintLayout:2.0.0-beta2`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="text1,text2,text3,text4,text5"
            app:flow_wrapMode="chain"
            app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"
            app:flow_horizontalBias="0"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="That is a very long textview that is very, very long"
            android:background="#00FF00"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text3 which is somewhat long"
            android:background="#0099FF"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text4"
            android:background="#999999"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="text5"
            android:background="#9900FF"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Result:

[image: flex with flow]

- `app:flow_wrapMode="chain"` allows for the chain to wrap to the next line when there's not enough space
- `app:flow_horizontalStyle="packed"` is necessary to be able to set the bias
- `app:flow_horizontalBias="0"` aligns the `Views` to the left
- `app:flow_horizontalGap="Xdp"` can be used to set a gap between the `Views`

Other wrap styles (`spread` and `spread_inside`) will not take the bias into account as they have a predefined way of laying out the `Views`

Comment: This solution also works in `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1` but not in `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha5`.  I can't use `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2` because it seems to have bugs.

Comment: I have a question to that. Is that possible to populate Flow layout from code? There is function called `addView(View view)`, but It is not working at least for me.