# Layout wrapping?

Tags: android

I'm a newbie and just trying something simple, but having a hard time to figure this thing out, hopefully you guys can help.
I'm creating a very simple app with a main page, and putting a bunch of buttons for the alphabets, right next from each other. Since there are too many buttons to fit into one single line on the screen, what is the best way to have it automatically wrap to the next line, considering viewing it on different screen sizes.

I understand it can be done by calculating the screen size, but it seems simple enough to be done by some simple ways with activity? been looking and trying the layout tags, but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not it's not possible to do this type of wrap, as I recall needing a similar thing with one of my own projects.

I know it's a pain but I would suggest having different layout files for different screen dimensions. Or as you suggested, fetching the calculated width of the container layout and doing something with the values.

Comment: wow, thanks for the info. I just started to play with the sdk and with all the cool layouts/libraries there, I didn't really think this is simply not possible :)

Answer (score 0):

This question has been ask a few times. Basicly your looking for FlowLayout in pure Java, there is a implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)