# Horizontal list of texts

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to get layout with horizontal non-scroll able texts where every textView tries to fit in the same line if there is enough space or it goes to the next line. I'm not really sure how to describe it but i mean something like this :

```
 +=================+
 |(text1) (text2)  |
 |(abc) (def) (ghi)|
 |(longertext)     |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 |                 |
 +=================+
```

I don't even know where to begin or how to look for something similar so any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android). It points to a FlowLayout implementation by Romain Guy. It will do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your textview

```
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```