# How to get ViewGroup after inflate layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have layout with my custom view like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

.....
```

And then I want to get ViewGroup from this xml files. But the manner that I know is just inflate the layout with View Inflater like this `LayoutInflater.inflate(R.id.my_layout)` and the return is just `View` And my layout is absolutely `RelativeLayout` that extends `ViewGroup`.

How can I get My Relativelayout as ViewGroup programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After inflating typecast it into relative layout. In android every layout is view which is super class of all views and viewgroups..

you have to typecast like this..

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
RelativeLayout lyLayout=(RelativeLayout) convertView;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this. This is an example for custom toast in android

```
public void showToast(Context context, String message) {
    // get your custom_toast.xml layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_activity,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_layout_id));
    // set a message
    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ToastMessageTV);
    text.setText(message);
    // Toast...
    Toast toast = new Toast(context);
    // toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.show();
}
```

Comment: The 2-parameter .inflate(..) call here was what I needed to get a custom ViewGroup to load - Thanks!   Fyi, in my case this solution was necessary to resolve loading the custom FlowLayout from this demo: http://hzqtc.github.io/2013/12/android-custom-layout-flowlayout.html