# Add Buttons Into layouts one by one on serval Lines

Tags: android

I want to develop the Messaging application like native Application. The Problem is when i add buttons after adding two or three buttons depending on name size will become like this
[image]

My Code is as below

```
   RelativeLayout tr = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.contacts_div);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                Button b = new Button(MainActivity.this);  
                b.setText(name);  
                b.setId(id);

                tr.addView(b,params);
                if(prev_id!=0)
                {
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,prev_id);

                }
```

I want if the enough space is not available the it will add on Next Line.
i try many posts in stack overflow but fail to solve this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want FlowLayout.  Search for it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do something like a FlowLayout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)

Comment: As said by @AleksG, you need to use Flow Layout to acheive this

Answer (score 0):

You should use a gridview for this.

Comment: I want to make it work for minSdkVersion=8 and gridview work for minSdkVersion=14

Comment: You are confused with GridLayout.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your button position through yout code once the text is set then you can see if the total width of your buttons is too big. Then you'll know when to place a button on the next line.

And as @Snicolas said use a `GridView`, the placement will be easier.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: HappyDump i want to make it work for minSdkVersion=8, if you can guide me how to get the total width and availaible width, it would be great help

Comment: The 'Button' Class inherits from 'Android.View' which has a 'getWidth()' method. From there you can add them up and add the padding/margin and get the total width. You can compare it also to your 'Activity' width.

Answer (score 0):

You should use FlowLayout. It's not standart android component, so you should find implementation you like. [E.g. this one is nice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)