# Linearly align items in a View to go to next line if space is filled

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to show buttons in an align as shown in the pic.

If i put them in a `Linearlayout` with orientation `Horizontal`, its ok.But how can i proceed to next line?

Following image shows some TextViews align Horizontally but i have no idea how to make them go to Next Line.

[image]

Comment: You have to use another linearlayout to achieve the second row if your orientation is horizontal or give your linear layout a fixed width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standard layouts (in the Andorid library) like the Swing's FlowLayout that can solve this problem. There are a couple of open source implementations of layouts that have the functionality you need. Here is an example: https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout
You could also read the answers to this question (which is essentially the same question): [How can I do something like a FlowLayout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)