# Layout that works like TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need a Layout that works like TextView. For example, if the text doesn't fit the whole line it goes to the next line.

I have whole bunch of TextViews and I want to add it to a layout from left to right and if it does fit anymore it goes to next line.

Does anyone have solutions?

Comment: Do you want your text to go to next line?

Comment: correct. I want my TextView not Text go to nextline. TextViews will be inside the layout.

Comment: `android:SingleLine:"true"`

Answer (score 1):

You are talking about a FlowLayout. Android does not currently have a FlowLayout, but one of the Android Devs (Romain Guy) shows how to make your own in this [lecture](http://www.parleys.com/#st=5&id=2191&sl=0)

Comment: Supplement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Add android:SingleLine="true" to your TextView.