# Implementing custom View and/or ViewGroup (Flow Layout) in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this:

[image: widget demo]

So, this is a container which can hold an arbitrary number of children. Each child is a simple text with border. Children may differ by their width. I assume this part can be implemented by extending the `TextView` widget (since it isn't clickable). Much more interesting thing here is the container for these bordered text views. It should support a regular `addView(child)` operation which automatically aligns the child according to the simple rule: if there is enough room within a current row - place child to the right of the last item in row. If there is no space - move child to the next row. So the basic logic seems quite similar to `TextView` or `EditText`: if text is too long, we display it in several lines. My idea is too extend `RelativeLayout`, but I still hope to find something easier.

The scheme I've described above (custom container + custom `TextView`) is not a mandatory, I'm just looking for ways to achieve this. Any thoughts guys?

Comment: button with custom style? Android will manage the most of things for you, and you just need to edit the background

Comment: I'm looking mostly for a way to implement a dynamic container. Sure, it's not a problem to customize a background, but I need to dynamically add several views (into single parent `ViewGroup`) and they should be properly aligned.

Comment: It seems to me you're describing a FlowLayout. A bit old but should be goold enough:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that pattern I was looking for is called `FlowLayout` (thanks to [nitzanj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365581/nitzanj)). There are several of implementations of it:

- [FlowLayout by blazsolar](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout)
- [FlowLayout by ApmeM](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

If you decide to write your own version, here are helpful guides about writing custom views:

- [Official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)
- [Dive into Android (video)](http://www.parleys.com/play/514892280364bc17fc56c0e2/chapter0/about)
- [Custom views (video, Google I/O 2013)](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325615129)