# How to place items according to their size?

Tags: android, android-xml

Currently, i develop a android application. In my activity, i would like to place my elements according to their size. i explain : i have 3 LinearLayout in a GridLayout like this :

[image]

GridLayout (2,2, horizontal) allow to put the LinearLayouts like this :

[image]

I would like to do the same, but no with GridLayout(**2**,**2**,horizontal), but just according to the size of the element.

For example, if the screen is large, it's possible to have the 3 LinearLayout on the same line and inversely if the screen is small, juste 1 LinearLayout by line.

I hope I have been clear, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried something like this before.. but I am using tons of LinearLayout and I am just playing with their layout_weight..

Comment: You can use different layout xml files according to the desired size (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). If the LinearLayouts size can be different you have to change the layouts placement dynamically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do something like a FlowLayout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This layout would be a "FlowLayout" which doesn't exist in standard.

But there are some open-source implementations of it around :

You should take a look at

https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout

or

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: Thanks, I have used it. Sorry for the duplicate, i didn't know FlowLayout before.

Comment: No problem ! There's no way to find for something - even on the internet - when you don't know its name, or even if it does exist...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can do.

You need to create different layout directory for different density devices.

For example **layout-ldpi**, **layout-hdpi**, etc. and define the required kind of layout inside these.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

And inside the different my_layout.xml file define either one, two or three linearlayouts you need.

Comment: @Orabîg Yes, but I am trying to give him advice

Answer (score 0):

Try these instead of gridlayout

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_VKZCqEnHblNDdiY2UxODgtYWNhNS00MmU4LWE4NDMtZjQ1OWI5MDMxZTVh/edit?num=50&sort=name&layout=list&pli=1#

Comment: try logging in to drive