# Layout withs items alignment in Android

Tags: android, layout, textview

I'm having three `TextViews` in a layout (First, Second, Third)

[image]

Now if the `FirstTextView` text or `SecondTextView` text is large then the `ThirdTextView` should go to the next line

[image]

I guess this functionality can be achieved thru HTML, but how can i acheive this in Native Android

And which layout should be taken to do this.

Comment: You're talking about a [`FlowLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android).

Comment: As per Mike You can achieve using this https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout for sample https://github.com/pchauhan/FilterSelectorListView

Comment: whats your requirement, i will suggest you to create spannable with different fonts and adding Clickable span in them. it will help you.

Comment: try wrap_content in textview width.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM... your solution worked