# Android dispose object created runtime

Tags: android, button, runtime, dispose

Im creating several buttons by using this function:

```
   private void setlayout(Integer numbers_of_buttons){

    // creating LinearLayout
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

    // creating LayoutParams
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    // set LinearLayout as a root element of the screen
    setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    Button[] butArray = new Button[numbers_of_buttons];

    for (int i = 0; i <  numbers_of_buttons; i++)
    {

        butArray[i] = new Button(this);
        butArray[i].setLayoutParams(params);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Btnparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) butArray[i].getLayoutParams();
        butArray[i].setText("i ... " + i);
        butArray[i].setId(i); // Setting the ids

        butArray[i].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, 0, 0);
        butArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        if (i != 0) {

            Btnparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, butArray[i -1].getId());
        }


        butArray[i].setOnClickListener(listener);

        linLayout.addView(butArray[i], Btnparams);



    }



}
```

Which is called when I click something in my NavigationDrawer and the parameter: numbers_of_buttons is retrieved by some query done in the sqlite database.

My only issues is that if numbers_of_buttons is > 7 i.e. (25) i can see only 7 of them.
This is because my scrren width is 720pixel (Nexus7).

So how am I suppose to handle this ?
My idea is 
 - calculate the widthness of the screen

```
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            System.out.println("DisplayWidth -> " + metrics.widthPixels);
```

- if getLeft() of last button create is > screenwidth than go to next row.

Can't find a way to do the second pseudocode.

EDIT - 1

```
 private void setlayout(Integer numbers_of_buttons){


    FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout(this);

    setContentView(flowLayout);


    Button[] butArray = new Button[numbers_of_buttons];

    for (int i = 0; i <  numbers_of_buttons; i++)
    {

        butArray[i] = new Button(this);
        butArray[i].setText("i ... " + i);
        butArray[i].setId(i);

        butArray[i].setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, 0, 0);
        butArray[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        butArray[i].setOnClickListener(listener);

        flowLayout.addView(butArray[i]);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do something like a FlowLayout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)

Comment: Oh, didn't see that.
That is a long answer doe, I was looking for something more shorter if possible xD

Comment: No worries. It's not a common thing in Android. You might wanna search the site for FlowLayout. There are at least a few other posts that give different options that may better suit your needs.

Comment: All right all right i'l give it a shot!
Thank you.

Comment: So i've tried using [link](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)
And this is what i've reached so far: [link]http://imgur.com/BB9cjAD

Is there a way to erase the blank space between the two rows of buttons ?
Edited my function.

Comment: Apparently, that layout spaces the lines out if there's extra room. I haven't had a chance to dig through the code yet, but, as a temporary fix, if you shrink the layout's height, it'll squeeze the rows closer together.