# Custom layout to accommodate variable number of buttons of variable width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-button

I have a layout with a fixed width and variable height. In this layout I want to have a variable number of buttons of variable width but fixed height. If the sum of the widths of the buttons is greater than the total width of the layout then the buttons should spillover to the next row. The number of rows is also variable. How to ensure the extra buttons spill over to the next row?

[image: Desired View Result]

Comment: This sounds like Swing's FlowLayout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the term "FlowLayout". I found a library that does the thing that I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library FlowLayout by Blazsolar does the above. It is very simple and easy to use.

https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout