# Layout Android wrap line

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, grid-layout, user-experience

i'm trying to achieve an android layout that looks like this:

[image]

Explaining, assuming that I have a button that add those blocks on my screen I want each block been added along screen left, and when the screen reaches the end, it should add a new line with blocks and so on.

I've looked to GridLayout, but it is very limited, and the weight property works only at api 21+.

So, is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Actually, GridLayout [works API 7+](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-gridlayout).

Comment: In practice, you are looking for a FlowLayout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do something like a FlowLayout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android)

Comment: That's it, I'm trying to use this flow layout, but now, how can I add itens on demand to it?