# Android add multiple Textviews programmatically to Layout line break

Tags: android, layout, textview, line-breaks

I need to add `TextViews` to a `Layout` (`RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` I don't care) programatically.

I want something like this:

[image]

After the `textview 4` there is no more space on the right side so the next `TextView` will be placed in a new Line bellow.

This is what I have done:

Create a `LinearLayout` in the `xml` file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

In my code, I loop over a list of `Objects` and add a new `TextView` for each objekt:

```
LinearLayout myLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);

for(MyObject object : myObjectList) {
          final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          params.setMargins(20, 0, 20, 0); // llp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);

          final TextView textView = new TextView(context);
          textView.setText(object.getName());
          textView.setLayoutParams(params);

          myLinearLayout.addView(textView, params);
}
```

But this is the result I get:

[image]

I have thought adding `LinearLayouts` vertically instead of `TextViews`, but still my problem is that I don't know when I need to add the next the next one, I mean, when there is no more space on the right side.

I have also tried it with `TableLayout` but still the same problem, I don't know when I have to add the next `row`.

Any ideas? Maybe there is a View that already solves that problem and I don't know...

Comment: Yes, I have just implemented in my app. You have create Custom ViewGroup something called FlowLayout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android

Comment: Thanks! that's exactly what I wanted. I did'n even know that this was possible, thanks!

Comment: Flexbox Layout may help you here: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout