# Show Items One After Another in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"/>
```

Here i'm adding some item using my custom adapter.

```
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, myArrayList);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id. listView1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In my custom Adapter, i used also a custom layout, where only one textVeiw:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/custom_textView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Everything is good. Working properly. The textView displaying texts line by line.
Example:

```
<TextView>
<TextView>
<TextView>
```

and so on..

But, i don't want to display text line by line. i want to display text one immediately after another.

Like:

```
<TextView><TextView><TextView><TextView><TextView><TextView>
```

but it'll take a new line when it reaches the end of its parent or device screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just try RecyclerView . it is better then listview ... u can display listitems in vertical or horizontal or in grid .

Comment: I think you are looking for something like a FlowLayout. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android

Besides,
1. You can get rid of the LinearLayout. If you really need that layout, then change the layout_width to "wrap_content".
2. Change the layout_width of your TextView to "wrap_content", otherwise it will always take the full width.

Comment: @RafiKamal the stackoverflow question link is not opening..

Comment: @KishorNR please give me tutorial link..

Comment: see this one http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-horizontal-vertical-recyclerview-example/

Comment: @KishorNR The view does not take new line or row when the text or list reaches the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you want horizontal list view instead of vertical list view.

Following Step are there :

**Implement Recyclerview in your layout (XML) “your_activity.xml” file.**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

**Implement List Adapter Item Layout (XML) “item_list.xml” file.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/lnrItem"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Implement Custome List Adapter “CustomListAdapter.java”**

public class CustomListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< CustomListAdapter.ViewHolder> { private Activity context; private ArrayList`<String> list = new ArrayList<String>`();

```
public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> list) {
this.context = context;
this.list = list;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);

return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
try {

holder.getTxtMessage().setText(list[position]);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return list.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private TextView txtMessage;

public ViewHolder(View view) {
    super(view);
    txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
}

public TextView getTxtMessage() {
    return txtMessage;
}
```

}

**Set Adapter in Activity “YourActivity.java” in OnCreate Method.**

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

RecyclerView horizontalRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.horizontalRecyclerView);

LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false); horizontalRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

```
 ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("First TextView ");
    list.add("Second TextView ");
    list.add("Third TextView ");
    list.add("Four TextView ");
    list.add("Fifth TextView ");
```

private CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(YourActivity.this, list); horizontalRecyclerView.setAdapter(topMemberAdapter);

}