# Recycler view with wrap content items horizontal and vertical scroll

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, adapter

hi i want to make a recycler view to take items horizontal as many as the screen fit but with vertical scroll like this image as example

[image]

I try with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` but it must specify the number of column want the column take as screen size any help will be good

Comment: The best option for this kind of layout is to use google flex-layout https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: I had the same requirement as yours and i achieved it by using this simple one [https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

Comment: You need a `FlowLayout` : https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android/42430027#42430027

Comment: What you ask is not easy or even possible with RecyclerView. I would recommend using a simple TableLayout. You do not need to specify columns in TableLayout.

Comment: @BurhanuddinRashid thanks very much that's work for me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `FlexLayoutManager` for this kind of design [FlexLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Here is a example snippet to use `FlexLayoutManager` in `RecycleView`

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) context.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
FlexboxLayoutManager layoutManager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(context);
layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.COLUMN);
layoutManager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.FLEX_END);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Their are many attributes to use `FlexLayout` Go through the documents on github

Answer (score -1):

As Burhanuddin Rashid commented, you should use the FlexBoxLayout. It has a LayoutManager for RecyclerViews, so the additional code will be minimal.
https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview