# How to create a UI with ConstraintLayout? Please refer to screenshot

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am creating a new UI in my code. Please refer to the below Picture. There are 3 views V1, V2 and V3. When V2 reaches to V3. The text has to go to the second line.

Can somebody help me out with this?

[image]

Comment: `When V2 reaches to V3. The text has to go to the second line` I don't think `ConstraintLayout` provides such arrangement . You can try using [FLowLayout or FlexboxLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474237/how-can-i-do-something-like-a-flowlayout-in-android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by below code, textView's Gravity u can set what u want,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivV1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvV2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="nakld"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivV3"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivV1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivV3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```